# Unordered list items second line, line-height

Tags: html, css

I have an unordered list in a narrow space. When the first (or could be any line) wraps to second line, the line height is the same as between the list items. I want it to be a little less between lines. In other words...

I want this:

• Blah blah blah Blah blah blah Blah blah blah 
  Blah blah blah Blah blah blah Blah blah blah

• Blah blah blah Blah blah blah Blah blah blah 
  Blah blah blah Blah blah blah Blah blah blah

not...

• Blah blah blah Blah blah blah Blah blah blah

Blah blah blah Blah blah blah Blah blah blah

• Blah blah blah Blah blah blah Blah blah blah

Blah blah blah Blah blah blah Blah blah blah

I hope that makes sense. I could put a line break between list items but that's too much space and on a larger screen it is not going to wrap anyway.

Comment: Well that doesn't show what I mean .... I want more space between bullets.

Comment: you can reduce the line-height and add margin for each list items

Answer (score 0):

In your css file you can use:
 
`li {
    white-space: nowrap;
 }`

But this will cause the text to overflow horizontally if there is no space

Answer (score 0):

You could add `margin-bottom` or `padding-bottom` (or -top) to your `li` items.

E.g.,

```
ul li { margin-bottom: ... }
ul li:last-child { margin-bottom: 0 }
```

(Hard to say more without context)

Answer (score 0):

You can add `margin-top` to `li`

```css
.a{
  width: 150px;
}

li{
 margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="a">
  <ul>
    <li>kwuh wgriu rgoib ergo</li>
    <li>kwuh wgriu rgoib ergo</li>
    <li>kwuh wgriu rgoib ergo</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```